# How can I use two modes in emacs (markdown and auctex)?

Tags: emacs

When I edit markdown in emacs I use markdown-mode. However I often have to type some math formulas in the markdown file (processed by `mathjax`). However for those math parts markdown mode is not very comfortable.

Is there a way to make emacs automatically switch to latex (auctex) mode (locally) when the point is between two `$` signs for example (`$\mathbb{R}$`) or between two double `$` signs for example

```
$$
\begin{align}
a = b
\end{align}
$$
```

?

**Edit**
I also want to have the font locking of the "local" mode.

**Edit 2**
I tried `mmm-mode`, but this doesn't handle font-locking correctly. I guess that `multi-mode.el` or `MuMaMo`-mode might be what I want. But I didn't figure out how to use this in my examples. So, if it is possible to do what I want with one of this or with another mode, it would be great if someone could post detailed steps howto apply it in my case as an answer.

Comment: You should try
[Org Mode](http://orgmode.org/) because it supports
[embedded latex](http://orgmode.org/manual/Embedded-LaTeX.html) with
[latex fragments](http://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-fragments.html#LaTeX-fragments)
that you can
[preview](http://orgmode.org/manual/Previewing-LaTeX-fragments.html#Previewing-LaTeX-fragments).
Though Org Mode is a bit
[more](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ho6nMWGtepY) than a markup
language.

Comment: @Daimrod How can I use org-mode to write markdown??

Comment: @student use org mode and export to markdown - http://orgmode.org/manual/Markdown-export.html . You can have multiple different languages in a markdown document....

Answer (score 4):

Emacs has several packages that help switching quickly and automatically between modes. The Emacs wiki has a page on [multiple modes](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes).

[Mmm-mode](http://mmm-mode.sourceforge.net/) is a common choice, but I expect each of the possibilities to have its ups and downs.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it. Can you add some details how to configure and use it in my case (I just installed `mmm-mode` via `aptitude`, what should I do next?)

Answer (score 3):

If you are specifically interested in avoiding interference of markdown-mode with math enclosed in $...$ or $$...$$, you can do M-x markdown-enable-math while markdown major mode is on, see http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/